# Filtering a collection in Meteor.js by a date range or word filter

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection in Meteor.js with properties which include a timestamp. For example:

```
Posts.insert({
    category: 'type1',
    text: 'hello world',
    time: new Date(2012, 2, 14, 15, 25),
});
```

I know I can filter the Collection by matching a parameter, e.g.

```
    Meteor.subscribe('posts', 'type1');

    Meteor.publish('posts', function(category) {
        return Posts.find({category: category});
    });
```

However, I want to also be able to filter in more advanced ways:
1) by the "time" field, e.g. all posts in between Jan 1, 2012 and Jan 1, 2013. 
2) by searching for all posts which have some word, e.g. "world" in the "text" field.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just combine [selectors](http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors) like so:

```
Posts.find({
  category: category,
  time: {$gte: date1, $lte: date2},
  text: new RegExp(searchTerm)
});
```